# write asterisk into file in shell

Tags: shell, output

i need to echo variables that contain asterisk(*), but the asterisk is always transferred with all file name on current dictionary. just like
    a.sh;
    b.sh;
    c.sh;
In c.sh

```
var="select * from userTable";
echo $var;
echo $var >> tmp.sql;
```

the output results become"select a.sh b.sh c.sh from userTable";
How should do in order to output asterisk(*)?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `echo "$var"` for stopping `*` to be used as a wildchar character. So use the following (note that `;` is not really needed in bash)

```
var="select * from userTable"
echo "$var"
echo "$var" >> tmp.sql
```

Comment: if I use \*, it will output \*.